# Augumented autocorrect in MS word - highlight changed words

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, autocorrect

I have early stage Parkinson's disease, which causes me some difficulty typing.

I have been looking for ways to improve MS-Word's (and ideally MS Outlook's) auto-correct facility as there are a lot of mistakes that don't get picked up, and it takes an age to manually correct them all and update the auto-correct list so avoid the same mistake in future - and you would be surprised how many wrong combinations there can be from fat fingered typing (or perhaps not :).

I found this very excellent suggestion elsewhere, which goes a long way towards the solution:

[Autocorrect for "fat fingers" - MS Word](https://superuser.com/questions/516137/autocorrect-for-fat-fingers-ms-word)

however, I am concerned that a word gets replaced with the wrong alternative word which would then have a correct spelling - and hence be missed by later spell checking, leaving potential errors that are hard to find.

I therefore have two questions:

1. Can someone suggest a mod to the script so that any changed words are highlighted?
2. Can someone give an idea of whether the script is likely to slow down large documents?

Comment: If the answer in that linked SU question helped out you should upvote it :)

Comment: @Mike, thank you for this, very much appreciated. I will try it out and let you know how it goes. I would upvote it, but as a rank noob I don't have the rights I'm afraid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Word but I'd try to modify the script as follows:

```
Sub AutoSpellCheck()
    Dim oSE As Range
    Dim oSC
    For Each oSE In ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors
        Set oSC = oSE.GetSpellingSuggestions
        If oSC.Count > 0 Then
        oSE.Text = oSC(1)
        oSE.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Else
        oSE.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
        End If
    Next oSE
End Sub
```

Misspelled words that are not changed should be highlighted in red; those that are changed should be highlighted in yellow.

I suppose the speed of running the script will depend partly on your computer's processing power.