# Is there a way to make Microsoft Word's autocorrect more aggressive?

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

Often when I'm typing quickly, trying to get a fleeting thought down, I make small mistakes typing. If I do it several times in a sentence, I have to go back and right click on each word and correct them.

MS word *does* autocorrect a lot of words, when it's clear enough what word it is.

What's annoying me is that sometimes I'll mess up a word that really has *no* alternatives it could be corrected to (other than the one intended), but Word won't autocorrect it! I even know it doesn't really, because I'll right click on it and it'll offer me the one possibility it knows, but for some reason it didn't change it to that.

For example, it fixes 'caogulation' to coagulation, but it doesn't change 'cogualation' even though right clicking shows coagulation as the only option. If there's literally one option, it seems like it's a safe bet to assume I was typing the word it's 2 letters from than just gibberish.

My phone's autocorrect seems smarter than it, which seems wrong. Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to make it more willing to correct words it knows?

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but a related one: If you commonly make certain typing errors, you can add your own words and substitutions.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks for the reply. MS Word should *really* have this built in though: my dinky phone does and it's not the *world's most popular word processor.*

Comment: There's an autocorrect library in Word, but you have to manually enter each misspelling with the word it ought to be.  Very tedious. To get to it, click File > Options > Proofing.  Though tedious, once set up it would be quite valuable.  I did a quick Google of "Microsoft word autocorrect list" and didn't find any pre-defined lists.

Comment: @BillOer, thanks for the response, but that's not exactly what I'm getting at -- I want it to correct it to the word it *already knows to*, but for some reason it's not. When I right clicked on "cogualition", it gave me "coagulation" and its plural, but nothing else. I'd like it to choose its top choice in situations like that.

Comment: @YungHummmma, I know exactly what you're saying, but the only way I know of to accomplish that in MS Word is to add that combination in the autocorrect library/list.  But I did find this on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/516137/autocorrect-for-fat-fingers-ms-word